# Left Join Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, inner-join

My mysql database structure looks as follows

**Products Table**

```
+----+--------+-------------+-------+
| id | itemid |    title    | price |
+----+--------+-------------+-------+
|  1 |      1 | Dell XPS 10 |  1000 |
|  2 |      1 | Dell XPS 13 |  1100 |
|  3 |      1 | HP 1        |  1100 |
+----+--------+-------------+-------+
```

**Items Table**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | description |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Laptop      |
|  2 | Monitors    |
+----+-------------+
```

**Parameters Table**

```
+----+--------+------------------+
| id | itemid |   description    |
+----+--------+------------------+
|  1 |      1 | Brand            |
|  2 |      1 | Series           |
|  3 |      1 | Color            |
|  4 |      1 | Operating System |
+----+--------+------------------+
```

**Specifications Table**

```
+----+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| id | productid | parameterid | description |
+----+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |         1 |           1 | Dell        |
|  2 |         1 |           2 | XPS         |
|  3 |         1 |           3 | Red         |
|  4 |         1 |           4 | Windows 10  |
|  5 |         2 |           1 | Dell        |
|  6 |         2 |           2 | XPS         |
|  7 |         2 |           3 | Black       |
|  8 |         2 |           4 | Windows 7   |
|  9 |         3 |           1 | HP          |
| 10 |         3 |           2 | 1           |
| 11 |         3 |           3 | Black       |
| 12 |         3 |           4 | Windows 10  |
+----+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

I am trying to out following result

```
 +----+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------------+----------------------+--------------------------+
 | id | productid |    title    | price | itemdescription | parameterdescription | specificationdescription |
 +----+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------------+----------------------+--------------------------+
 |  1 |         1 | Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop          | Brand                | Dell                     |
 |  1 |         1 | Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop          | Series               | XPS                      |
 +----+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------------+----------------------+--------------------------+
```

Instead of this I am getting

```
 +----+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------------+----------------------+--------------------------+
 | id | productid |    title    | price | itemdescription | parameterdescription | specificationdescription |
 +----+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------------+----------------------+--------------------------+
 |  1 |         1 | Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop          | Brand                | Dell                     |
 |  1 |         1 | Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop          | Brand                | XPS                      |
 |  1 |         1 | Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop          | Brand                | Red                      |
 |  1 |         1 | Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop          | Brand                | Windows 10                      |
 +----+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------------+----------------------+--------------------------+
```

I am using following mysql query

```
SELECT products.title, products.price, items.description, parameters.description, specifications.description
FROM products
LEFT JOIN items ON products.itemid = items.id
LEFT JOIN parameters ON parameters.itemid = items.id
LEFT JOIN specifications ON specifications.productid = products.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Secondly is it possible to have all the parameters & specifications listed in same row?

```
 +----+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
 | id | productid |    title    | price | itemdescription | specificationdescription | specificationdescription | specificationdescription |
 +----+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
 |  1 |         1 | Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop          | Dell                     | XPS                      | Red                      |
 +----+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how to improve the database structure, I am open to ideas to optimize it. Thanks

Following is the output to @Shakir answer

```
+-------------+-------+-------------+------------------+-------------+
|    title    | price | description |   description    | description |
+-------------+-------+-------------+------------------+-------------+
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Brand            | Dell        |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Series           | Dell        |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Color            | Dell        |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Operating System | Dell        |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Screen Size      | Dell        |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Touchscreen      | Dell        |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Brand            | XPS         |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Series           | XPS         |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Color            | XPS         |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Operating System | XPS         |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Screen Size      | XPS         |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Touchscreen      | XPS         |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Brand            | Black       |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Series           | Black       |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Color            | Black       |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Operating System | Black       |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Screen Size      | Black       |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Touchscreen      | Black       |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Brand            | Windows 10  |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Series           | Windows 10  |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Color            | Windows 10  |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Operating System | Windows 10  |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Screen Size      | Windows 10  |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Touchscreen      | Windows 10  |
+-------------+-------+-------------+------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: check itemid in parameter table for brand and series it is 1. so your results id correct. if you want expected results then put 2 item id in parameter table before series

Comment: The itemid = 1 because both are parameters of item = Laptop

Comment: Are you asking why you're getting brand in all 4 rows instead of brand, color, series and os? And yes, it's possible. Look into group by and group_concat

Comment: @Flyer Yes I want it to show brand color series instead of repeating brand again and again. And let me give group_concat a look too.

Answer (score 0):

try this and show results

```
SELECT products.title, products.price, items.description,  
parameters.description, specifications.description
FROM products
INNER JOIN items ON products.itemid = items.id
INNER JOIN parameters ON parameters.itemid = items.id
INNER JOIN specifications ON specifications.productid = products.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: | Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Brand            | Dell        |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Series           | Dell        |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Color            | Dell        |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Operating System | Dell        |
| Dell XPS 10 |  1000 | Laptop      | Brand            | XPS         |

Comment: by edit your answer and it give right output as you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works.

```
SELECT 
  products.title, 
  products.price, 
  items.description, 
  (
     SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(spec.description SEPARATOR ' ')
     FROM specifications as spec
     WHERE spec.productid = products.id
     GROUP BY spec.productid
  ) AS `specificationdescription`
FROM products
INNER JOIN items ON products.itemid = items.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE spec.productid = products.id ) AS `specificationdescription` FROM prod' at line 10

Comment: Moving Where before Group By fixed the syntax error. But the issue with this is that all specification descriptions are in one column in one line with no separation. So if I want to run a search query on it, I wouldn't be able to.

Comment: You can modified above SQL by joining `products` table with `specifications` table using `products.id=specifications.productid` and include WHER.